# Bootstrap 3 several toggle buttons

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three toggle buttons on mobile view. I would like the content of each to appear separately, i.e. when I click on one button, the content of the other closes and is replaced by the clicked button's one. Right now when I click on each button the content of other buttons doesn't go away anywhere, it just appears under each other. Is it possible to switch this somehow?

```
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        Button 1 content
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-2">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        Button 2 content
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-3">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        Button 3 content
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">
  Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-2">
  Content 2
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-3">
  Content 3
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried making it an accordion? [Bootstrap Accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)

Comment: I tried, but something doesn't work. I don't quite understand how to add it to toggle buttons in a navbar...

Answer (score 0):

The data-target for your buttons are currently the same for all three, "#bs-navbar-collapse-1".  You need to make them match the id of the div that you want them to open and close.

```
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    Button 1 content
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-2">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    Button 2 content
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-3">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    Button 3 content
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">
      Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-2">
      Content 2
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-3">
      Content 3
  </div>
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. Now I've changed it.